# How do I populate a dependent dropdownlist from database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know there are several threads and articles about dynamically populating a dropdownlist/dependent dropdownlist from database, my issue though is uniquely different.

I have two dropdownlists, ddlAssets and ddlNumCheck

ddlNumCheck is a dependent dropdownlist to ddlAssets dropdownlist.

For instance, let's say that ddlAssets has 4 (1,2,3,4) values and according to business requirements, if you select 1 from it, then 1 gets added to ddlNumCheck dropdownlist.

If you select 2, then 2 (1,2) gets added to the ddlNumCheck dropdownlist.

Finally, any value from 3 and above, 3 (1,2,3) gets added to the ddlNumCheck dropdownlist. 3 is the maximum that can be added to ddlNumCheck from ddlAssets.

Finally, depending on what value you choose from ddlNumCheck, a row with three column names is automatically created.

If you select 2 from the ddlNumCheck, 2 rows with their column names are automatically created.

If you select 3 from ddlNumCheck, 3 rows with their column names are automatically created.

You can then fill out these columns and submit to the database.

This entire scenario works great. I gobbled up from online the part where ddlNumCheck dropdownlist creates rows dynamically when a value is selected from it is.

The issue that I have now is that when trying to query the DB to retrieve the data I just submitted as described above, we would like to see the the value of both dropdowns selected by default.

For instance, if I selected 4 from the ddlAssets dropdownlist and I selected 2 from the ddlNumCheck dropdownlist and then I submit them successfully to the db, when I query the
db to load this data and display them on our form, we would like 4 to be the default selected value for ddlAsets dropdown and we would like 2 to be the default selected value for
the ddlNumCheck dropdown.

So far, when I run the code below, all form fields including ddlAssets dropdownlist get their values displayed and ddlAssets gets it value selected by default. ddlNumCheck dropdownlist does not display its value.

What am I doing wrong?

Below is some relevant code snip.

```
    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
        Dim query As String = "SELECT m.clientname,m.assetnumber,m.cost,m.purchaseDate,a.assets FROM mainTable m inner join AssetsData a on m.AssetID=a.AssetID where m.ID =" @someID
        command.Connection = connection
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@someID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID
        command.CommandText = query
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                 
        While reader.Read()
            clientname.Text = reader("Result").ToString()
            ddlAssets.Text = reader("Result").ToString()
            ddlNumCheck.Text = reader("Result").ToString()
        End While
    
        connection.Close()
    End Sub

    <tr>
        <td width="(100/2)%">Total # of assets at property:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAssets" CssClass="ChangeWidth" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAssets_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>How many assets did you upgrade?
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNumCheck" CssClass="ChangeWidth" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlNumCheck_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    Private Sub populateAssets()
        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constring)
        Dim com As String = "Select * from AssetsTable"
        Dim adpt As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(com, con)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        adpt.Fill(dt)
        ddlAssets.DataSource = dt
        ddlAssets.DataBind()
        ddlAssets.DataTextField = "Assets"
        ddlAssets.DataValueField = "AssetID"
        ddlAssets.DataBind()
        ddlAssets.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select--", ""))
    End Sub
     
Protected Sub ddlAssets_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("Assets", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("AssetID", GetType(Integer))
    If ddlAssets.SelectedValue = "1" Then
        dt.Rows.Add("1", "1")
        ddlNumCheck.DataSource = dt
        ddlNumCheck.DataTextField = "Assets"
        ddlNumCheck.DataValueField = "AssetID"
        ddlNumCheck.DataBind()
        ddlNumCheck.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select--", ""))
    ElseIf ddlAssets.SelectedValue = "2" Then
        dt.Rows.Add("1", "1")
        dt.Rows.Add("2", "2")
        ddlNumCheck.DataSource = dt
        ddlNumCheck.DataTextField = "Assets"
        ddlNumCheck.DataValueField = "AssetID"
        ddlNumCheck.DataBind()
        ddlNumCheck.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select--", ""))
    ElseIf Integer.Parse(ddlAssets.SelectedValue) >= Integer.Parse("3") Then
        dt.Rows.Add("1", "1")
        dt.Rows.Add("2", "2")
        dt.Rows.Add("3", "3")
        ddlNumCheck.DataSource = dt
        ddlNumCheck.DataTextField = "Assets"
        ddlNumCheck.DataValueField = "AssetID"
        ddlNumCheck.DataBind()
        ddlNumCheck.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select--", ""))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `if you select 1 from it, then 1 gets added to ddlNumCheck dropdownlist` can you share this code?

Comment: Are you asking to summarise all this, is what your asking is how to programmatically set the selected item in your combo?

Comment: @Hursey, no, not at all.

What I am asking is that I can select a number say 4 from ddlAssets dropdown and a number say 2 from ddlNumCheck dropdown and submit them to the database. 

When I use the query I posted to retrieve the records I submitted, I would like them to be selected as default on the dropdowns. For instance, 4 will be preselected on ddlAssets and does but 2 is not getting preselected on ddlNumCheck and I would to know how to fix that.

Comment: You haven't included the entire code of the page, so we can't specifically determine at what point you are calling either the "populateAssets()" sub, or the sub that contains your data retrieval ..... however, presumably at the point where you are doing the data retrieval, the "ddlNumber" object doesn't have all of the items in it that you're expecting it to have (given that you're dynamically building the items based on user action).

Comment: My immediate suggestion is that after the ddlAssets.Text = reader("Result").ToString() line, you'll need to just call the ddlAssets_SelectedIndexChanged() method (you can just pass Nothing as the parameter values, since you're not using the parameter anyway).  That will populate the ddlNumber drop-down with the required items, and you'll then be able to set the selected value based on the data that you retrieved

Comment: @Craig, thank you for your suggestions. Please understand that the populateAssets() method has nothing to do with the issue I am having. I only posted it because Chetan asked for it and I didn't ask why he wanted to see it. I just it as you can see to populate the ddlAssets dropdownlist.

Your suggestion to call the ddlAssets_SelectedIndexChanged() method is a great one but how should it be used to add value to ddlNumbCheck dropdown?

Comment: @Tairoc - oh, I did obviously have a little bit of confusion between "ddlNumCheck" and "ddlNumber" ... in my mind I'd been thinking those two were the same thing.  You did, however, say that the available items in "ddlNumCheck" are dynamically added based on the selected value of "ddlAssets".  So, potentially there's a difference in the way your code is behaving between the actual user interaction vs. you trying to set drop-down list selections programatically.  As I also said, you haven't included all of the code of your page, which makes it hard for others to judge exactly what's happening

Comment: @Craig, once again, great eyes and great catch. Thank you for that. That was a typo. Yes, ddlNumber is same as ddlNumCheck. I corrected it.

As far as more codes, the only other relevant code to share is pageLoad() event where the populateAssets method is passed. That's it! Like I said, all it does is just populate the ddlAssets dropdownlist. I do not have any other code to share.

The code I shared that queries the DB and assigns the values from db to the form fields is the only code I have and it shows how I am trying to get ddlNumCheck dropdown to preselect value from db.

Comment: You just hit the nail on the head with this : "given that you're dynamically building the items based on user action". I am sure that's why ddlAssets dropdown gets its value selected by default and ddlNumCheck doesn't. I am hardpressed to believe this issue has been addressed before but unfortunately, I have not seen anything out there to help with resolving this.

Comment: @Tairoc.  So, without perhaps still fully understanding exactly what your page is doing, I suspect the sequence of events is this: 1) load page, this populates the assets drop-down, 2) user selects from the assets drop-down, which posts-back the page and then code dynamically sets the items that appear in the "num check" drop-down, 3) user selects from the "num check" drop-down, which posts-back the page and the code dynamically sets a number of rows in a grid, 4) user fills in value in the grid and posts the page 5) results from the grid are saved to a database table

Comment: 6) the page reloads to display records from the database (I'm not entirely sure, from your code example, what the specific criteria is for when records from the database are displayed) .... 7) when the page reloads, the "assets" drop-down is populated - but, at this point - the "num check" drop-down has no items in it (?), 8) data is retrieved from the database, 9) attempts are made to set the selected value for "assets" and "num check" ......

Comment: Does that sequence essentially sound correct?  If so, then what you are missing is that when you set the selected value of the "assets" drop-down (based on the value in the retrieved data), you then need to programatically populate the items in the "num check" drop-down list so that when you try to set the selected value for that drop-down, the value is actually available in the list

Comment: @Craig, your description of sequence of is almost completely correct. Only #6 is not correct. Picking up from #5, once results are saved to a database table, the user is presented with "record successfully saved. The user searches the DB to ensure that the record submitted, did save correctly. It is during the search the the user enters an ID of the recently inserted record to view it. The following description by you is EXACTLY where I am stuck

Comment: " If so, then what you are missing is that when you set the selected value of the "assets" drop-down (based on the value in the retrieved data), you then need to programatically populate the items in the "num check" drop-down list so that when you try to set the selected value for that drop-down, the value is actually available in the list "

When I posted the code that queries the db to retrieve records, I am basically saying, this is all I have and don't know what else or how else to get the data I need to appear the numChec list. You described it so well.

Comment: @Tairoc.  So, I go back to something that I suggested earlier - after you set the selected value for the "ddlAssets" drop-down (from the retrieved data), you can just add a new line of code that calls "ddlAssets_SelectedIndexChanged(Nothing, Nothing)" - then, after that line of code you can set the value of the "ddlNumCheck" drop-down.  I will confess that I'm also a bit confused about your lines inside the reader.Read() loop - you're referencing reader("Result"), but there isn't a "Result" column in the query that populates the reader .... so that's a bit confusing

Comment: In addition, if you are going to set the selected value of the drop-downs from the retrieved data, you should really use <drop-down>.SelectedValue, rather than .Text - because I imagine it's actually the "value" from the drop-down list that is being saved to the database.  (Admittedly, if you've just got the numbers 1 -> 4, then chances are the value and text are the same, but it's probably better practice to set .SelectedValue anyway

Comment: @craig, oh my goodness, it WORKED, can you believe it!

WOW!, WOW!!

To answer your question about using selectedValue vs .Text. As far as I know, you use selectedValue if you are passing value from dropdown to text or some such but if you are passing query results, whether it is a textbox control or not, receiving field is always .Text, as far as I know but I can't believe you fixed this, oh my world!
Thank you so much. WOW

Comment: I need to accept your answer please. That's the least I can do if you can change it so I can accept it.

Comment: @Tairoc.  The question of "value" vs. "text" is probably a whole other discussion .... but what you've described is not really a proper understanding of when you would use one or the other.  It all comes down to what is being saved in your database, and then where that corresponding value appears in your drop-down list choices.  In your instance, I'd suggest that things are working the way you think they should work because - in your drop-down list - both the "value" and the "text" are the same, ie. the numbers

Comment: But let's say you set your drop-down list up so that it displayed the words "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", but the corresponding "values" for those choices were 1, 2, 3, 4.  In that instance, you would end up saving 1, 2, 3 or 4 (depending on the user's choice) to your database.  Then, when you retrieved the data from the database, you would try and set <drop-down>.Text to be (for example) 2 - however, the "text" that corresponds with a value of 2 would actually be the word "Two".  Therefore, you would need to set <drop-down>.SelectedValue = 2 (rather than .Text).  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Craig, it's hard to argue with someone who solved my problem in less than an hour and I swear I have been struggling with this for close to two days.

I have one more to complete this but I will post that another time. I need to give myself some time to try and work it out and that is that now that ddlNumCheck is getting its value selected, the row or rows associated with each value needs to be displayed as well but I will see what I can do to resolve this.

Thank you so, so much for your tenacity and ingenuity.

Comment: @Craig, I think you are looking at dropdownList as it were RadioButtonList.

Yes, in dropdown, you have selectedValue for the value="1". You also have selectedItem which points to the text, and using your example, it is Two. That's how I know DropDownList to work

Comment: For example, this sample here ~<option value="dave">Dave</option>~, selectedValue will be dave and selectedItem will be Dave with capital D.

In any case, I would thin that if you are passing a value, say resultset to this same, assuming the name of the dropdown is DropDownList1, it will DropDownList1.Text= rs("something"). So far, that's how I know to do it. Now, I know you a wealth of knowledge in this but I have always known it to be done that. If could help with an example of how you do it, that will new knowledge to my cap.

Answer (score 0):

All the poster is asking is to setup the cascading combo boxes in REVERSE order.

I mean, say we have a cascade of City, and then we select a Hotel from that city selection.

In that 2nd case, like DARN NEAR EVERY drop down, we have the hidden value (such as PK value), and THEN we have the display text.

So, lets setup a cascade on City --> hotel Name seleciton.

So, say this markup:

```
<div style="padding:25px">
<div style="float:left">
    <h3>Select City</h3>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server" Width="168px"
        DataValueField="City" 
        DataTextField="City" AutoPostBack="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
    <h3>Select Hotel</h3>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotels" runat="server" Width="168px"
        DataValueField="ID" 
        DataTextField = "HotelName"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboHotels_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
    <div style="text-align:right">
        Hotel Pick (id) = <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotelID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        Hotel Name = <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotelName" runat="server" Width="240px"></asp:TextBox> <br />
    Enter new Hotel id (go backwards) <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdBackWards" runat="server" Text="setup combo's (go backwards)" CssClass="btn"
        OnClick="cmdBackWards_Click" />
    </div>
</div>
```

So city combo ---> Hotel list -- select Hotel

So, this code, rather common.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' load up City combo
        LoadCityCbo

    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadCityCbo()
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT City from City ORDER BY City")
    cboCity.DataSource = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    cboCity.DataBind()
    cboCity.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select City", "")) ' Add blank row selecting
End Sub

Sub LoadHotelCbo()

    Dim strSQL As String =
            "Select ID, HotelName FROM tblHotels 
             WHERE City = @City ORDER BY HotelName"

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboCity.SelectedItem.Text

    cboHotels.DataSource = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    cboHotels.DataBind()
    cboHotels.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select Hotel", 0))

End Sub

Protected Sub cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' cascade City and limit hotels from given city.
    If cboCity.SelectedIndex > 0 Then

        LoadHotelCbo()

    End If

End Sub


Protected Sub cboHotels_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    If cboHotels.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        txtHotelID.Text = cboHotels.SelectedItem.Value
        txtHotelName.Text = cboHotels.SelectedItem.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

So, on page load - fill out city list

User select city, then drill down to hotel.

We now see, have, enjoy this:

[image]

Ok, but of course after we do this cascade, I would think that "Mr. Obvious" in tihs question is then what happens if I LOAD the reocrd with this selection?

Why of course, I have to load up the combo boxs, but I have to FIRST get the 2nd casecade value, and SETUP the first combo, and of course THEN set city, and THEN cascade again, and THEN select the EXISTING value the user selected.

That code is "kind of" reversed, but if we are smart, we can simple re-use the 2nd cascade code AFTER we setup the city.

Then out of that cascaded list, we of course setup the 2nd combo based on that saved/previous vaale (presuamrlty from some CRUD edit form).

So, lets do that:

The code is this:

(based on a given Hotel ID).

```
Protected Sub cmdBackWards_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = @ID"
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtNewID.Text
    Dim rstHotels As DataTable = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    Dim sCity As String = rstHotels.Rows(0).Item("City")

    ' select correct city for cbo combo
    cboCity.Text = sCity
    LoadHotelCbo()
    cboHotels.Text = txtNewID.Text

End Sub
```

So, we actually have to PULL that Hotel reocrd, since we need the City that was the cascade part. We don't have to re-load the first combo, but ONLY set the city, then call 2nd combo load (to cascade), AND THEN set the value based on that id.

We thus get/see this:

[image]

So, you have to PULL that 2nd cascaded PK value, get the (city) in this case, and then select the correct value in the first cbo, call the 2nd cascade, AND THEN set the pk id selection of that 2nd combo.

Comment: great to hear from you.

Craig actually got it right. What he provided is exactly what I needed.

However, you could help me by making the selected value automatically open the row or rows associated with value displayed on ddlNumCheck.

For instance, if ddlNumber check has the value of 1 selected, I would like it to automatically display the row associated with it with the columns and their completed values. If numCheck has a value of 2, it opens two rows, The rows by the way are inside repeater control.

Comment: The two dropdowns are outside repeater while the rows are inside repeater.