# How to display results of dynamically generated rows from dynamically populated dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When inserting records into the database, there are two form dropdownlists that are critical to our business rule, ddlAssets and ddlNumCheck.

ddlAssets has 8 values dynamically populated from the database.

Then ddlNumCheck is conditionally populated by selecting from ddlAssets.

For instance, selecting 1 from ddlAssets automatically adds 1 to ddlNumCheck
Selecting 2 from ddlAssets automatically adds 2 values (1,2)
Selecting any number from 3 and above, can only add a total of 3 (1,2,3) to ddlNumCheck dropdownlist

These scenarios work perfectly for us.

After submitting records to the database, we query database tables to populate the form fields including the two dropdownlists mentioned above.

Initially, I had problem selecting as default, the value for ddlNumCheck.

This was resolved a couple of days ago, thanks to @Craig for his assistance.
For more about this, please refer to the following link:
[How do I populate a dependent dropdownlist from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75727652/how-do-i-populate-a-dependent-dropdownlist-from-database/75729229#75729229)

There is one final piece of this puzzle that I have been struggling with.

Once we query the database to populate the form fields, the value of ddlAssets is selected as default and the value of ddlNumCheck is selected as default.

How do we display the rows associated with the default value of ddlNumCheck?

For instance, if the value of dllNumCheck is 1, we would like the repeater row that is dynamically created during insert operation to be displayed along with its colum name values.

If the value of ddlNumCheck is 2, we would like two rows of repeater control to be displayed.

If the selected default value is 3, we would like three rows of Repeater control to be displayed.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

I tried using these methods but they do not working:

```
Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
         For Each item As RepeaterItem In DynamicRepeater.Items
            Dim ddlWater As DropDownList = TryCast(item.FindControl("ddlWater"), DropDownList)
            Dim txt_amount As TextBox = TryCast(item.FindControl("txt_amount"), TextBox)
            Dim purchaseDate As TextBox = TryCast(item.FindControl("purchaseDate"), TextBox)

Dim query As String = "SELECT m.clientname,m.assetnumber,m.cost,m.purchaseDate,a.assets,m.WaterSize FROM mainTable m inner join AssetsData a on m.AssetID=a.AssetID where m.ID =" @someID
    command.Connection = connection
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@someID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID
    command.CommandText = query
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
             
    While reader.Read()
        clientname.Text = reader("Result").ToString()
        ddlAssets.Text = reader("Result").ToString()
        ddlAssets(Nothing,Nothing)
        ddlNumCheck.Text = reader("Result").ToString()
        ddlWater.Text = reader("waterSize").ToString()
        cost.Text = reader("cost").ToString()
        purchaseDate.Text = reader("purchaseDate").ToString()
        
    End While
   Next
    connection.Close()
End Sub
and
    Protected Sub ddlNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim query As String = String.Format("SELECT TOP {0} * FROM mainTable", If(Integer.Parse(ddlNumber.SelectedValue) >= 3, 3, Integer.Parse(ddlNumCheck.SelectedValue)))
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
            Using sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                Using dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Dim Items As List(Of ItemsModel) = New List(Of ItemsModel)()
    Dim rows As Integer = 0
    Integer.TryParse(ddlNumber.SelectedValue, rows)

    For i As Integer = 0 To rows - 1
        Items.Add(New ItemsModel())
    Next

    DynamicRepeater.DataSource = If(Items.Count = 0, Nothing, Items)
    DynamicRepeater.DataBind()
End Sub

<asp:Repeater ID="DynamicRepeater" runat="server" onitemdatabound="DynamicRepeater_ItemDataBound">
         <HeaderTemplate>
         <table border="1">
             <tr>
             <td><b>Water Size</b></td>
             <td><b>Cost</b></td>
             <td><b>Purchase Date</b></td>
             </tr>
         </HeaderTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
             <td>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWater" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"">
               <asp:ListItem Text="Select" selected="True" Value="" />
           </asp:DropDownList>                        
             </td>
             <td>
             <asp:TextBox ID="cost" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </td>
             <td>
             <asp:TextBox ID="PurchaseDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </td>
         </tr>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
         </FooterTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater><br />
```

Comment: but how can you store 3 values into ONE ddl? That ONE row is ONE row in repeatr. Thus, say you are to select 2 or 3 values. How you going to save/store/enjoy/use/have/retrive the  3 values? this means for each ddl 1 selecting, you require a insert into that child table attached to this one row we are working on.  So, its not clear on 2nd ddl is storing 3 values - that requires inserts into another child table then, right ? (and I don't see any insert code when a ddl 1 is selected before "moving" or display into ddl 2. Perhaps that supposed to occur upon save?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, how are you sir.

Ok, please allow me to explain further.

Let's say for instance that a user selects value 2 from the ddlAssets dropdown, this automatically populates the ddlNumCheck dropdown with 2 values (1,2). All of this was discussed a few days ago on the link that I attached. If the user selects say 2 from the ddlNumzCheck dropdownlist, it automatically creates two rows in the Repeater control with the three columns I showed in the html code I posted. This works great. We just would like to have a row or two automatically displayed depending on what value is select-

Comment: --continue from last post. It depends on what value is selected by default from ddlNumCheck. If ddlNumCheck is selected by default from the results of query, that means that three rowes were dynamically created in Repeater control with the column values already inserted. We would like those three rows to be automatically displayed by virtue of 3 being selected by default on ddlNumCHeck. I hope this makes sense. I have been banging my head since two days now trying to work this out with no luck.

Comment: I am happy to show you the code that stores the values to a database table. However, the code the populates ddlNumCHeck by selecting from ddlAssets is on the link I provided.

Comment: @Tairoc - hello, again!  Your repeater should just display the results that come from your data-reader .... if you have 1, 2 or 3 rows that you previously saved in the database, then as long as your data-reader is selecting those rows, the "repeater" should just take care of displaying those rows, because it just loops on each record in the data source.  You've got bits of code that you're putting in your "SelectedIndexChanged" event for the drop-down list - but me, personally, I probably wouldn't have the code in those places

Comment: @Craig, good to hear from you again sir. I added the code to the SelectedChanged event just to show the various ways I tried getting the results to display.

When I ran the code on the reader, it is not recognizing the those three fields from the Repeater. I kept getting error message that they are not declared which is not true. So, I suspected they are not getting recognized by the reader.

Comment: You should do some research on the event cycle of your Asp.Net pages .... you should be able to identify those instances when a user is submitting data (to be saved to the database), vs. when the user is doing a lookup (that needs to display data from the database).  The way that you approach your coding - or, more specifically, the points in the page's life-cycle where you perform certain functions - may differ between those two different situations

Comment: @Tairoc - are you really receiving an error message?  If so, then it would be useful to include details of any actual errors that you are seeing, to allow others to assist.  We don't have your full application and database with us to actually be able to debug what's going on, so as much information as you can provide will assist others further

Comment: @Craig, right but the fields that are being read by the reader is many. I just chucked them off to keep the code short. They are all being recognized by reader except those three that are from the Repeater control.

Comment: Correct, I have already indicated the only three that are returning errors. ddlWater, cost.Text and PurchaseDate.Text. Those are the only three on the Repeater control. The error is that they are not declared. I showed the html code that has the three form fields. It's really frustrating when you think you are coding it correctly and expecy it to work but it doesn't.

Comment: @Tairoc - I really think you've got some fundamentals not right in what you're trying to do.  See here for a relatively simple example of using a data-bound Repeater.  I think you need to assess your own code against this example, and aim to get to a point where the repeater is successfully displaying the records you're retrieving from the database .... https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Repeater-ItemDataBound-event-in-ASPNet-example.aspx  (sorry, I'll admit that I don't really have time left in my day, today, to assist you further at this point)

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your efforts though. The difference between the OnItemDataBound event used in that link and what I am using is that mine is using search based on a parameter. They are both using the FindControl() to associate a variable with the form field in the Repeater control You get the same behavior by using FOR...NEXT loop like I am using.

Comment: @Craig, I would like to thank you once again for providing that link. I was able to grab the BindRepeater() method and since I already have the OnItemDataBound() method, I was able to reference the Repeater controls there.

Then added the BindRepeater() method to the Search() method and it worked.

This didn't resolve all my issues as much as I thought it would.

For instance, the rows displayed need to be persistent but are not because when you select a higher value from the dropdown, the displayed rows reset. If you could reach deeper into your technical knowledge bank with further...

Comment: ..guidance on how to handle this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much for being the only guru to understand exactly what I am trying to accomplish, absolutely no disrespect to anyone else as it could easily have been my fault not explaining things well.

Thank you!

Comment: @Tairoc - as I alluded to in my previous comment, you need to think about the flow of what is happening with your page.  I don't think we're really talking about "technical" things right now - we're talking about the user's experience as they are interacting with the page, and how your code responds to those different events.

Comment: What I mean is, a) user loads the page up for the first time - how should the page behave, and how should changes to drop-downs, etc., affect what is happening on the page.  Then you need to think about other events that will occur - b) user changes drop-down selections, but hasn't entered any new row data yet, c) user has entered new row data, but then changes drop-down selections, d) user submits data to be saved to the database, e) user wants to view previously submitted data

Comment: How the controls on your page respond to those different events is probably going to be slightly different, so you need to be able to identify when those different events occur.  Maybe the click of a particular button helps you identify exactly what action the user has taken?  Maybe it's a combination of the different states of controls on your page?  It sounds like you at least have your code behaving in the way you expect it to - now you need to determine the different events that are occurring, and only have the necessary blocks of code run when required

Comment: @Craig, the sequence or flow of events as described by you are the things user actually asks us to do.
1) Let me take it from d) of your comments. User describes how the layout looks look when she wants to view previously submitted data. That is working as per requirement.
2), When she selects from the dropdowns and submits, when viewing submitted data, she wants to see, among other things, the values submitted from the dropdowns to be selected as default. With your help the other night, that works now according to specs. The user also says that the Repeater row or rows created during...

Comment: Inserts should automatically be displayed when one of the dropdowns, ddlNumCheck has a default value selected. For instance, if ddlNumCheck has a default selected value of 1, one row should be displayed in Repeater; if 2, two rows should be displayed; if 3, three rows should be displayed.

Today, again, thanks to the link you provided, that is now working.

Finally, the user says if the displayed row is one which is ddlNumCheck has a default value of 1, then they should have the ability to change the ddlNumCheck value to 2 or 3 and in which case, additional blank row or rows should be...

Comment: displayed while retaining the one row or two that was already displayed.

The layout and process flow are designed and coded that way so far.

Notice that none of your recommended solutions requires overhauling of my code. 

The code follows the flow as required by the user.  Like other developers who may be as gifted as some of you, we constrained by the technical ability to solve all technical problems. That's why we are here :)

The issue I have now what additional code is needed to ensure that when a new blank row or two are added, how to ensure the displayed row persists.

Comment: I will do the coding if I get some guidance on how to approach it or what I need to add or change to make it happen. No changes are needed in the flow of the code. Just need some missing pieces.

Thanks again.